# Error with Generics and Method References

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Java 8, and due to client needs, this cannot be changed.

Basing off a recent question I asked, I have a new problem.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
public <E, T, G extends ChangeThing> void dothing(String string1,
                                                  String string2,
                                                  Function<List<E>, Tuple2<List<T>,Integer>> convertThingy,
                                                  Function<Integer, List<G>> fetchChangesFunction,
                                                  Class<T> classType) {
```

`G` refers to this class:

```
public class Thingy implements ChangeThing {
```

Which is implementing:

```
public interface ChangeThing {
```

And is used in the following method:

```
public List<Thingy> findAllThingyChanges(int version) {
```

Calling the `dothing` method above with the `findAllThingyChanges` method works just fine.

However, this class (as suggested in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58757435/5136448) to my previous question):

```
public final class Test<E, T, G extends ChangeThing> {

    private static final Dao DAO = new Dao();

    private static final List<Test> TEST_LIST = Arrays.asList(
            new Test("string1", "string2", ThingyConverter::convertThingy, DAO::findAllThingyChanges, Thingy.class)
    );

    private final String string1;
    private final String string2;
    private final Function<List<E>, Tuple2<List<T>, Integer>> converterFunction;
    private final Function<Integer, List<G>> fetchChangesFunction;
    private final Class<T> classType;

    private Test(String string1, String string2,
            Function<List<E>, Tuple2<List<T>, Integer>> converterFunction,
            Function<Integer, List<G>> fetchChangesFunction,
            Class<T> classType) {
        this.string1 = string1;
        this.string2 = string2;
        this.converterFunction = converterFunction;
        this.fetchChangesFunction = fetchChangesFunction;
        this.classType = classType;
    }
}
```

Gives me the following error on that one item in the static list:

```
incompatible types: bad return type in method reference
    List<Thingy> cannot be converted to List<G>
where G is a type-variable:
    G extends ChangeThing declared in class Test
```

What am I missing?

It sounds preposterous that a `List<Thingy>` cannot be converted to a `List<Thingy>`. Since `List<Thingy>` (which is what `G` is supposed to become) is the exact return type of the `DAO::findAllThingyChanges` method being passed in as argument 4. So I have to be missing something.

Comment: Why is `Test` raw in `TEST_LIST`?  It should have `<>` after it, with type arguments if necessary.

Comment: If there's anything wrong with that class, which came as an answer from the previous question, I'm completely open to fixes / adjustments. The main goal is to get rid of that first function call I listed at the top of the question because it's called 40-60 times, in 4 places, where nothing changes except some of the parameters. I want to get rid of the copy / paste job. To that end I want to collect all the relevant stuff together in one place (my first attempt was an enum, but it seems to have a problem with generics) and simply call the method once in a loop, with the appropriate getters..

Comment: I added `<?, ?, ?>` to `List<Test>` on the list declaration line, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: It wouldn't. Add concrete types. Both in `List<Test>` and in `new Test`.

Comment: Getting nothing but compiler errors about expecting various syntax / grammar bits. Can you give an example?

Comment: What are `E`, `T`, and `G` all supposed to be in `new Test(...)`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was able to make the errors go away by changing it up slightly so that the declaration and setup of the list are separate (setup is in a static block). Initialization is `List<Test<?, ?, ?>>` and when I add the entries later in the static block, it's `TEST_LIST.add(new Test<>(/*blah blah*/));` For whatever reason I couldn't get the `asList(/* ... */)` thing to work. However, the next problem is that when I actually call the `dothing()` method at the beginning of the question, it complains about various things. (to be continued)

Comment: Having a getter for the `fetchChangesFunction` method reference is fine. But it can't seem to reconcile that `convertThingy` is, in fact, a properly matching method, and a straight getter for the `classType` complains about `inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints CAP#3,Class1` where `Class1` is the same as the class that will be passed in as the class for the List<T>` in the `Tuple2` input parameter in `convertThingy` function.

Comment: This is a _lot_ of code with very complicated generic constraints that I can't just figure out in my head, but in general, I'm going to bet on that issue being that it really shouldn't be `<?, ?, ?>` but three  _actual_ types, whose values you need to figure out.